# Symfony2: how to iterate over (and analyse) a group of Doctrine entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, iterator, extend, entities

From my Doctrine repository I am able to get an `array` (or alternatively an `IterableResult` object) containing some *CountryInformation* entities from my DB.

Now I need to build some statistics from this information, e.g.:

- how many people live in the 10 biggest/poorest/... countries (combined)?
- which countries have a GDB between x an y?

In the old PHP world I would have done this with a custom Iterator class `CountryInformationIterator` holding all the entities and providing above methods. Now I'm thinking I should maybe extend above `IterableResult` class, but I don't now how to force Doctrine to return this `IterableCountries` object then.

The Symfony docs (book/cookbook) don't offer information on that problem.
So what is the most elegant way to do custom iteration in Symfony2?

- Which pre-existing classes can I use / extend?
- How do I do that, and where?

If you have an example, that would be really helpful since I already spent a lot of time searching for a solution.

Comment: At this point (depending on how large a data set I'm dealing with) I generally just use SQL & aggregate the data I want. It's a lot more efficient than iterating over a bunch of objects and counting data that way. Doctrine is great for operating on individual objects but a pretty poor fit for data aggregation (imo). That said, you could probably get most of what you're after using DQL aggregate functions: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for simple aggregations. But two questions:

- How would you compute the median or certain quantiles? MIN, MAX and SUM can't do that :-/
- And still my main concern remains where do you put the logic? Can't have it in the controller or the view!

In your linked example my problem would be to find the percentage of bank accounts that lie within a certain top or bottom quantile - so I need separate logic, which I can't put into an entity as there is no entity `bank` with OneToMany `account` entities.